# How to set the creator of the case when using email-to-case?

Tags: force.com

I have setup email-to-case using a separate user. However whenever the automated case is created it is using created by 'my user account'. I want to change this to some other user. Can anyone help me with how I can achieve the same. Any setting that I am not aware about ?

Comment: Are you talking about the created by field or the case owner field?

Answer (score 1):

Apex Email Services allow you to specify the context user, which will be Created By User, details see here:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com

you might get away with using a different email address per context user. To make it more dynamic you'll have to go with Mohith suggestion via SFDC support.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a case with sfdc to provide a functionality where you can modify createdate on insert.This is supported by sfdc but only on raising a case with them